# Cannot read property 'state' of undefined in one place and in another it can read

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Can anyone help me to undestand why in this sentence

```
if (this.state.ind == index) {return <div key={index}>
```

it shows mistake but when I print this.state.ind in p it works without problems?

```
var Countries = React.createClass({  
getInitialState: function() {
    return {
        countries: [],
        ind: 0,
        loaded: false,
    };
},

componentDidMount: function() {
    this.getCountry();
},
```

calling to json file

```
getCountry: function() {
    // take this to variable me -> used inside AJAX-callback functions
    var me = this;
    // create ajax call to json file, handle done and fail
    $.ajax({
        url: 'json/countries.json',
        cache: false,
        dataType: 'json'
    }).done(function(data) { 
        me.setState({countries: data.asia, loaded:true});   
    }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        me.setState({infoText: textStatus+":"+errorThrown});
    });
},
```

code for button

```
handleClick() {
this.setState({ind: this.state.ind + 1});
},


render: function() {    
    return (
        <div>
            {this.state.countries.map(function(country,index){
```

here doesn't work

```
               if (this.state.ind == index) {return <div key={index}>
                <p>{country.name}</p> 
                <p>{country.capital}</p>
               </div>;}
            })}
```

here works

```
            <p>{this.state.ind}</p>
            <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Next</button>
        </div>
    );
}

});
```

Answer (score 0):

use following code as we cannot use if-else in jsx

```
render: function() {    
    return (
        <div>
           {this.state.ind == index && <div key={index}>
            <p>{country.name}</p> 
            <p>{country.capital}</p>
             </div>}
      ....
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use if/then/else blocks in JSX.  The better form is to pre-filter the list to only what you want to render prior to the map statement.

```
render: function() {
    const testInd = this.state.ind;
    const indStates = this.state.countries.filter( function(c, ind) { return c.ind === testInd } );
    return (
       <div>
           { indStates.map( function( country ) {
               <div key={index}>
                   <p>{country.name}</p> 
                   <p>{country.capital}</p>
               </div>
           })}
       </div>
    }));
}
```

Typed this in without testing, but it seems like what you want.

Comment: i am very sorry to ask but now it tells "Cannot read property 'map' of undefined" and i just can't get what is wrong because react is new to me.

Comment: @Seiggailion I think that'll fix it.

Comment: I guessed today that that might help but after that it complains about "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined at eval" in this line "const indStates = this.state.countries.filter( function(c, ind) { return c.ind === this.state.ind } );". I just can't get what is wrong doesn't matter how much i read and try =(

Comment: Try that then?   I moved the resolution of "this.state.ind" to a local variable declaration, which should scope fine.  The local variable should then be accessible.

Comment: I am very embarrassed to bother you again but now it doesn't show any mistakes though it doesn't print information. Without mistakes i have no idea what could i even google about.

Comment: At this point you could start debugging in your browser using the javascript debugging tools.   I'd start with the data that's getting sent down from the server.  Does data.asia have any data in it when you get the response from the server? Try outputting the values of "testInd" and "indStates" using console.log to see if they're appropriate, etc.

Comment: If you find a bug in my response, please let me know so I can fix it.